# OpenJDK8 и Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

При пересборке OpenJDK9 для настройки рабочей среды в Visual Studio я использовал команду make hotspot-ide-project. Сейчас пересобираю OpenJDK8, но когда я использую команду make hotspot-ide-project, пишет, мол такой команды не существует.
Подскажите, как настроить рабочую среду Visual Sutdio под OpenJDK8.